# Unit testing class where I simply fetch a value based on a key

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a simple phone book class (this class is extracted because I inject a different phone book for testing) that has ~10 entries and I'm wondering. Do I create a test for each phone book entry or simply test to ensure a few phone numbers are successfully fetched based on the key?

The interface is quite simple.

```
public interface IPhoneBook
{
    string Lookup(string key);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a test to test fetching an entry that should exist.

Have a test to test fetching an entry that should not exist.

That should be enough, if the data structure is as simple as you describe.

---

Ask yourself - what value would testing all entries give you over the above tests? If none, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you inject a class for testing purpose only, you should not care about testing the injected class. You should test the class calling the stubbed methods, and assume your injected class works fine. If you are not sure about your injected class, you should test it separately, it is not even going into production, is it?

Answer (score 1):

[Moq - Site](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)

```
        var mockPhonebook = new Mock<IPhoneBook>();
        mockPhonebook.Setup(x => x.Lookup(It.IsAny<string>()))
                     .Returns("SamplePhonebookEntry");
```